# Как создать новый столбец в DF по категории?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть исходный DF:

```
dD
0,05
0,15
0,25
0,95
```

И второй DF с категориями значений:

```
Ot  Do  SP
0   0,1 0,6
0,1 0,2 0,6
0,2 0,3 0,8
0,3 0,4 1,25
0,4 0,5 1,6
0,5 0,6 2,5
0,6 0,7 4,5
0,7 0,8 5,5
0,8 0,9 6,5
0,9 1   8
```

Правая граница нестрогая!

Нужно в соответствии со значением в первом DF поставить значение SP.
То есть, на выходе нужно получить нечто такое:

```
dD      SP
0,05    0,6
0,15    0,6
0,25    0,8
0,95    8
```

Comment: Во втором DF у первых двух строчек совпадают значения `SP` - это опечатка или намеренно так сделано?

Comment: Да , все верно, впринципе от 0 до 0,2 значение будет SP -0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала избавимся от дупликатов в первом DF (данный шаг можно пропустить если все значения в столбце `d2['SP']` уникальные):

```
In [161]: t = d2.groupby('SP')[['Ot','Do']].agg({'Ot':'min', 'Do':'max'}).reset_index()

In [162]: t
Out[162]:
     SP   Ot   Do
0  0.60  0.0  0.2
1  0.80  0.2  0.3
2  1.25  0.3  0.4
3  1.60  0.4  0.5
4  2.50  0.5  0.6
5  4.50  0.6  0.7
6  5.50  0.7  0.8
7  6.50  0.8  0.9
8  8.00  0.9  1.0
```

теперь подготовим границы интервалов:

```
In [163]: bins = t[['Ot','Do']].stack().drop_duplicates()

In [164]: bins
Out[164]:
0  Ot    0.0
   Do    0.2
1  Do    0.3
2  Do    0.4
3  Do    0.5
4  Do    0.6
5  Do    0.7
6  Do    0.8
7  Do    0.9
8  Do    1.0
dtype: float64
```

и соответствующие категории:

```
In [165]: labels = t['SP']

In [166]: labels
Out[166]:
0    0.60
1    0.80
2    1.25
3    1.60
4    2.50
5    4.50
6    5.50
7    6.50
8    8.00
Name: SP, dtype: float64
```

наконец воспользуемся функцией [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) для категоризации значений:

```
In [180]: d1['SP'] = pd.cut(d1['dD'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)

In [181]: d1
Out[181]:
     dD   SP
0  0.05  0.6
1  0.15  0.6
2  0.25  0.8
3  0.95  8.0
4  0.00  0.6
```

---

**PS:** для отладки бывает полезным не указывать категории (`labels`), чтобы увидеть получившиеся интервалы:

```
In [182]: pd.cut(d1['dD'], bins=bins, right=False)
Out[182]:
0    [0.0, 0.2)
1    [0.0, 0.2)
2    [0.2, 0.3)
3    [0.9, 1.0)
4    [0.0, 0.2)
Name: dD, dtype: category
Categories (9, interval[float64]): [[0.0, 0.2) < [0.2, 0.3) < [0.3, 0.4) < [0.4, 0.5) ... [0.6, 0.7) < [0.7, 0.8) < [0.8, 0.9) < [0.9, 1.0)]
```

Comment: Для нуля писать будет `NaN` хотя должен `0.6`

Comment: @Max52, исправил ответ...

Comment: Благодарю! Выручили. Сейчас еще по циклам вопрос напишу